# Fail while downloading MySQL Server from MySQL installer

Tags: mysql

I was trying to download MySQL server from MySQL installer. I tried to download all versions of Visual C++ from 2013 to 2017 both x64 and x86. And yet it didn't execute and keep shown me fail.

As shown in the pic down here:

[image]

Comment: Are there some logs you can check to see what went wrong?

Comment: Your screenshot does not show an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually :)

here is how:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P99dA0yGY8g